# Ansible - how to compare items between 2 dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, ansible, ansible-facts

I have 2 dictionaries, 1 containing products and some variables for each product (including database location), and 1 containing databases in different locations and the way to connect to each.

example -
databases -

```
databases:
  - location: db1
    db_host: 10.0.0.1
    db_port: 1111

  - location: db2
    db_host: 10.0.0.2
    db_port: 2222

  - location: db3
    db_host: 10.0.0.3
    db_port: 3333
```

products -

```
product_list:
  - portfolio: 'product1'
    startDH: '{{ days }} 16:00:00'
    endDH: '{{ yest }} 06:30:00'
    location: db1

 - portfolio: 'product2'
   startDH: '{{ days }} 05:15:00'
   endDH: '{{ days }} 16:00:00'
   location: db2

 - portfolio: 'product3'
   startDH: '{{ days }} 01:30:00'
   endDH: '{{ days }} 15:00:00'
   location: db1

 - portfolio: 'product4'
   startDH: '{{ days }} 15:30:00'
   endDH: '{{ days }} 22:00:00'
   location: db3
```

In my playbook, I'm tying to run a SQL query with for each product on it's correct db.
looping over products list is quite easy, but when I'm trying to compare each product (using the 'location' item) I'm always getting the last db in the databases dictionary.
an example play would be -

```
  tasks:
- name: Set database variables for each product
  set_fact:
     db_info: "{{ lookup('vars', item.location) }}"  # Use a dictionary to store db_host and db_port for each product
  with_items: "{{ product_list }}"

- name: test vars
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: host is "{{ db_info.db_host }}" in "{{ item.location }}" with "{{ item.portfolio }}".
  loop: "{{ product_list }}"
  loop_control:
      loop_var: item
```

the output would always state that {{ db_info.db_host }} is db3's IP (the last db in this dictionary).
How do I make it so the each product would be paired with it's correct database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary of the databases

```yaml
  db_dict: "{{ dict(databases|map(attribute='location')|
                    zip(databases)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  db_dict:
    db1:
      db_host: 10.0.0.1
      db_port: 1111
      location: db1
    db2:
      db_host: 10.0.0.2
      db_port: 2222
      location: db2
    db3:
      db_host: 10.0.0.3
      db_port: 3333
      location: db3
```

Use it in the loop

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: >
          host is {{ db_info.db_host }}
          in {{ item.location }}
          with {{ item.portfolio }}
      loop: "{{ product_list }}"
      vars:
        db_info: "{{ db_dict[item.location] }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: |-
    host is 10.0.0.1 in db1 with product1
  msg: |-
    host is 10.0.0.2 in db2 with product2
  msg: |-
    host is 10.0.0.1 in db1 with product3
  msg: |-
    host is 10.0.0.3 in db3 with product4
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    databases:
      - location: db1
        db_host: 10.0.0.1
        db_port: 1111
      - location: db2
        db_host: 10.0.0.2
        db_port: 2222
      - location: db3
        db_host: 10.0.0.3
        db_port: 3333

    days: 7
    product_list:
      - portfolio: 'product1'
        startDH: '{{ days }} 16:00:00'
        endDH: '{{ days }} 06:30:00'
        location: db1
      - portfolio: 'product2'
        startDH: '{{ days }} 05:15:00'
        endDH: '{{ days }} 16:00:00'
        location: db2
      - portfolio: 'product3'
        startDH: '{{ days }} 01:30:00'
        endDH: '{{ days }} 15:00:00'
        location: db1
      - portfolio: 'product4'
        startDH: '{{ days }} 15:30:00'
        endDH: '{{ days }} 22:00:00'
        location: db3

    db_dict: "{{ dict(databases|map(attribute='location')|
                      zip(databases)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: >
          host is {{ db_info.db_host }}
          in {{ item.location }}
          with {{ item.portfolio }}
      loop: "{{ product_list }}"
      vars:
        db_info: "{{ db_dict[item.location] }}"
```

- It is not necessary to create the dictionary *db_dict*. Instead, you can select the item in the loop

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: >
          host is {{ db_info.db_host }}
          in {{ item.location }}
          with {{ item.portfolio }}
      loop: "{{ product_list }}"
      vars:
        db_info: "{{ databases|selectattr('location', '==', item.location)|first }}"
```

- All options depend on unique locations. There will be different results if the list of databases' locations is not unique. For example, you can also use the *last* item

```yaml
      vars:
        db_info: "{{ databases|selectattr('location', '==', item.location)|last }}"
```

Comment: for some reason creating the dictionary (maybe because something I failed to mention, that both lists of variables are in separated vars_files), but selecting the item in the loop did the trick. Thanks!!